# Mongoid ignores collection.insert if at least one duplicate exists

Tags: mongoid

I have a unique index setup, with `drop_dup: true`

`index({ key1: 1, key2: 1 }, { unique: true, drop_dups: true })`

When inserting multiple records, I would like the non-duplicates to succeed, similar to MySQL's

`INSERT IGNORE INTO table ...`

.. or even `INSERT INTO table ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

So if I have a record:

`Model.collection.insert({'key1'=>'not-unique', 'key2'=>'boo'})`

It seems that the following call doesn't do anything.

`Model.collection.insert(`

`{'key1'=>'not-unique', 'key2'=>'boo'},`

`{'key1'=>'im-unique', 'key2'=>'me-too'}`

`)`

Is there a way to at least insert `{'key1'=>'im-unique', 'key2'=>'me-too'}` on the 2nd call?

Thanks!

Comment: What versions of Rails and Mongoid are you using?

Comment: Rails 3.1.1 and Mongoid 3.0.0 .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are looking for insert batch with continue_on_error
and not single document update/upsert of which I think you are already informed.

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#insert-instance_method

With the 10gen driver, an equivalent of your example with a User model would be:

Gemfile

```
gem 'mongo'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

test/unit/user_test.rb (excerpt)

```
col = Mongo::Connection.new['sandbox_test']['users']
col.insert({'key1'=>'not-unique', 'key2'=>'boo'})
assert_equal(1, User.count)
col.insert([{'key1'=>'not-unique', 'key2'=>'boo'},{'key1'=>'im-unique', 'key2'=>'me-too'}], :continue_on_error => true)
assert_equal(2, User.count)
```

The above works in a simple unit test.

Mongoid 3 uses the Moped driver instead of the 10gen driver.
In the 1.1.6 gem that you are using, moped does not support options / flags,
but Durran added flags to the insert method circa July 28 in github.

https://github.com/mongoid/moped/commit/2c7d6cded23f64f436fd9e992ddc98bbb7bbdaae

https://github.com/mongoid/moped/commit/f8157b43ef0e13da85dbfcb7a6dbebfa1fc8735c

As of mongoid 3.0.3 with moped 1.2.0, the following insert batch with continue_on_error works.

```
Model.collection.insert([{'key1'=>'not-unique', 'key2'=>'boo'},{'key1'=>'im-unique', 'key2'=>'me-too'}], [:continue_on_error])
```

Note that the primary parameter to the insert method for batch insert is an Array object
enclosed in square brackets - the square brackets are missing from your post.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I'll test this out and report back.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That worked perfectly. Is there a `collection.update`, similar to SQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a batch `upsert`. I found this quote from the [MongoDB site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%7B%7Bupserts%7D%7D) "_It is important to remember that upsert can only insert a single document._": does that mean no batch updates?

Comment: Yes, you correctly read that there is no batch upsert.  Note that the term batch update may be a bit confusing.  While the update request only takes single document args for criteria/selector and objNew/document, multiple documents may be updated as a "batch" in the update(-non-insert) case.

Comment: Note that there are important differences between Mongoid::Persistence::Operations(included in User), Moped::Collection(User.collection), and Mongo::Collection. Mongoid (ODM by Durran Jordan) has insert(only), update(only(?)), and upsert methods on your model. Moped (Ruby driver by Bernerd Schaefer) has just the insert method on Moped::Collection; update and upsert methods are "protocols" that chain to the find method. Mongo (Ruby driver by 10gen) has insert, update-with-upsert-option, and save (upsert or insert) methods on Collection.

Welcome to open source - you get many choices!