# Rails duplicate key error for mongodb in batch insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

On my Rails4.2 app using MongoDB v5, Well I have some data in this array format which I have to insert in the database:

```
array_to_be_inserted = [
  {'unique_key' => '12234'},
  {'unique_key' => '3214'},
  {'unique_key' => '32142'}
]
SomeModel.create(array_to_be_inserted) //For inserting
```

In the database I already have lets say '12234' unique key, so this throws an exception and the code stops, and the remaining data does not get inserted (i.e. 3214 and 32142 keys will not get inserted even though they are not present in the database). Even if I do rescue Exception , the code continues but the insert still fails.

Is there any way to get around this which can be instant ?

I already tried to make an array of those unique keys and did `SomeModel.in(array_of_unique_keys)` and then filtered out the array so that the new array becomes this:

```
array_to_be_inserted = [
  {'unique_key' => '3214'},
  {'unique_key' => '32142'}
]
```

I use this for array filter:

```
array_to_be_inserted = array_to_be_inserted.select { |x| existing_data.none? { |y| x['unique_key'] == y['unique_key'] } }
```

But the problem is that, that array filter takes time and memory too and meanwhile some other person stores that unique key already and code fails again once again.
I need something which can be instant, like can be done in one single query, for example in MySQL we can simply do `INSERT IGNORE INTO`, isn't there something for this which is fast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been facing a similar issue with a Rails application and a postgresql db. I need to insert millions of rows and if I try to check the existing primary keys my app crashes.

I am using [`bulk_insert gem`](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) which allows the option `ignore: true`. However, postgresql syntax does not support the 'INSERT IGNORE' statement, so it was quite an useless option in my case.

```
destination_columns = [:title, :author]

# Ignore bad inserts in the batch
Book.bulk_insert(*destination_columns, ignore: true) do |worker|
  worker.add(...)
  worker.add(...)
  # ...
end
```

If you are using `activerecord-import` you can refer to [this blog post](https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2016/08/19/importing-data-and-handling-conflicts-in-ruby-on-rails-applications):

```
Author.import(
  [:name, :key],
  rows_to_import_second,
  on_duplicate_key_update: [:name],
  validate: false
)
```

However, it seems that this gem also doesn't have an adapter for mongo ([check the source code](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/tree/master/lib/activerecord-import/adapters)).

I guess that a combination of these two SO answers might fix your problem:

- [Insert many mongo - continue on error ruby / Ruby Mongo equivalent for mysql insert ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002382/insert-many-mongo-continue-on-error-ruby-ruby-mongo-equivalent-for-mysql-ins)
- [Mongoid ignores collection.insert if at least one duplicate exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752991/mongoid-ignores-collection-insert-if-at-least-one-duplicate-exists)