# Insert many mongo - continue on error ruby / Ruby Mongo equivalent for mysql insert ignore

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Hi when I try to do continue on error for insert many it doesnt work in mongoid.

**I set the following unique index**

db.push_notifications.createIndex({ actor_vid: 1,campaign_id: 1 },{ unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { campaign_id: { $exists: true } } })

PushNotification.collection.insert_many([{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 9},{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 8}],:continue_on_error => true, :safe => false)

PushNotification.collection.insert_many([{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 9},{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 10}],:continue_on_error => true, :safe => false)
 throws

**Mongo::Error::BulkWriteError: Mongo::Error::BulkWriteError**
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/bulk_write/result.rb:184:in `validate!'
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/bulk_write/result_combiner.rb:73:in`result'
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/bulk_write.rb:65:in `execute'
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/collection.rb:385:in`bulk_write'
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/collection.rb:363:in `insert_many'
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.1.3/lib/mongoid/query_cache.rb:168:in`insert_many_with_clear_cache'
    from (irb):133
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`start'
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
    from /home/deploy/.bundler/notification_service/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in`require'
    from script/rails:6:in `'

**OR**
What is the **mongo** equivalent for **mysql insert ignore**? I need to perform insert_many operation with bypassing error on **unique** keys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**continue_on_error** is not an option for insert_many , use **unordered inserts** instead.By specifying **ordered: false** , inserts will happen in an unordered fashion and it will try to insert all requests.Including an try catch block will make sure it won't break after an exception, so you are achieving an MYSQL INSERT IGNORE equivalent.
If your using ROR, this is how your code should be,

```
begin
 PushNotification.collection.insert_many([{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 10},{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 11},{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 12}],{:ordered => false}) 
 PushNotification.collection.insert_many([{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 10},{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 11},{:campaign_id => "1",:actor_vid => 13}],{:ordered => false}) 
resque => ex 
 puts ex.message 
end
```

So, after the block is executed , you will have 4 new entries inserted and 2 `Mongo::Error::BulkWriteError` Exception.